# $\sum_{i=1}^n |\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid k | i\}|$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

What is $\sum_{i=1}^n |\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid k | i\}|$ asymptotically (as a function of $n$)?

(I'm summing, for each of $1,\dotsc,n$, its number of divisors)

Or at least, what's the best upper bound you can find?

Comment: The number of divisors of $n$ is usually denoted $d(n)$ or $\sigma_0(n)$.

Comment: Does it behave like harmonic sum?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n$.

**Dirichlet's Asymptotic Formula.** (Theorem 3.3 in Tom Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*) *For all $x\geq 1$, we have
$$\sum_{n\leq x} d(n) = x \log x + (2C-1)x + O(\sqrt{x}),$$
where $C$ is Euler's constant,*
$$C = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\log n\right).$$

The proof involves writing the sum as
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n) = \sum_{d\leq x} \sum_{q\leq x/d} 1,$$
and interpreting it as counting lattice points in the $qd$ plane; the lattice points with $qd=n$ lie on a hyperbola; then one can get that
$$\sum_{q\leq x/d} 1 = \frac{x}{d} + O(1),$$
and from this and the fact that
$$\sum_{n\leq x}n^{\alpha} = \frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1} + O(x^{\alpha}),\qquad \text{if }\alpha\geq 0,$$
one derives that
$$\sum_{n\leq x}d(n) = x\log x + O(x).$$
The more precise formula uses the symmetry of the corresponding hyperbola along $q=d$. Apostol's book has all the details.

The error term $O(\sqrt{x})$ can be improved: you can see a summary in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem); best estimate so far is due to Huxley, who proved the error term is $O(x^{(131/416)+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon\gt 0$. Hardy and Landau proved that the smallest exponent possible is at least $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: In terms of the lower bound and $\Omega$ results, the best known is due to Soundararajan and states that $$\Delta(x)=\Omega\left(\frac{x^\frac{1}{4}\left(\log x\right)^\frac{1}{4} (\log \log x)^\beta}{\left(\log \log \log x\right)^\frac{5}{8}}\right)$$ where $\alpha=\frac{3}{4}\left(2^\frac{4}{3}-1\right)$.  Now, the very interesting thing is that "it is plausible the first three exponents above are optimal." (quote from Montgomery and Vaughns book, Chapter 2 Notes)  I remember reading this quite a while ago and finding it very strange. See: http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2003/36/1987

Answer (score 8):

You can find a good summary in the following [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem)

The main term in the estimate for $\sum_{i=1}^n d(i)$ is 
$$n\log n +(2\gamma -1)n,$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's $\gamma$.

There is a large literature on the error term. Dirichlet got $O(n^{1/2})$, and it is known that one cannot do better than $O(n^{1/4})$.

**Note**: For a number-theoretic function, this is a fantastically precise estimate. We have a dominant term, $n\log n$, that gives us the asymptotic behaviour. We have also an explicitly known correction term $(2\gamma-1)n$.  And, by number-theoretic estimate standards, the error term is quite small compared to $(2\gamma-1)n$.